# How do you make a side by side box plot for a yes/no variable?

Tags: rstudio

I’m working in R and I’m very new to it. I’ve tried a number of things and can’t seem to get it to work. I’m attempting to view income based on yes or no, college or no college.

Comment: Can you share what exactly you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried at first boxplot(dataset522$CollegeStatus, dataset522$Income) but I want to see the yes and no variables apart on the same boxplot. Like I said I'm very new so I'm not sure how it all works just yet.

Comment: I figured it out!

Comment: Congratulations! Consider posting your solution as an answer, so that other people might benefit from it.